# Having trouble in displaying data with an outer and inner foreach-loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm facing a problem I cannot solve.
And I do not know whether it can be solved.
I've been searching and trying all day long.
I deeply hope that you can help me.

I want to create tables with tabular data.
Therefore I need names of persons (in my case students) and some output like 'how many hours has he been sick'.

I get the data from a MySQL DB and call them with PHP.
This is just an example, but describes what I need:

1. For every student there should be a new table-row. (no problem)
2. For every student I need the hours he has been sick.

This should be displayed in a table under the name.
My problem is the hours one has been sick are shown under each name. I give you an example what it looks and what it shall look like:

```
Shall look like:
|Name    |Hours Been Sick   
|Sam      | 0                               
|Samantha | 3                               
|Sammy  | 25                            


Looks like:
|Name    |Hours Been Sick   
|Sam      | 0 3 25                  
|Samantha | 0 3 25                  
|Sammy  | 0 3 25
```

This is because of my first foreach-loop.
I just cannot see a way to put the data out in another way.

This is my code:

```
//For every student 
foreach ($someQuery as $student => $value) {
$name = ucfirst($student);
    echo "<thead><tr><td>" . $student . "</td>";
    echo "</tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    //for every student the hours he has been sick
                    foreach ($hoursBeenSick as $name => $value) {
                            $value = round($value, 1);
                            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"
                    }
[more code]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
 //for every student the hours he has been sick
 foreach ($hoursBeenSick as $name => $value) {
   $value = round($value, 1);
   echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
 }
```

with

```
$value = round($hoursBeenSick[$student], 1);
echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
```

Comment: Unfortunately replacing doesnt't work. Still print out every value for every student.

Comment: without the foreach ? are you sure?

Comment: All data changed to 0 and I didn't notice it. That was why I thought it didn't work. Thank you. Of course you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

```
foreach ($hoursBeenSick as $name => $value) {
  $value = round($value, 1);
  echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"
}
```

with :

```
echo "<td>" . round($hoursBeenSick[$student], 1) . "</td>"
```

Comment: Unfortunately replacing doesnt't work. Still print out every value for every student.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the hours_been_sick in the same query as the students, you'll have a nice array of data to print out.

Can't say exactly without knowing what your table looks like, but something like

```
SELECT student_name, hours_sick FROM students_table, sickness_table
WHERE students_table.student_id = sickness_table.student_id
```

Comment: Hi, I already get the data from one query. My problem is that they're printed out for every student. Ty anyway.

Comment: What does your query look like?